# Create a new column that is the concatenation of all preceeding columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to concatenate all columns in a pandas dataframe separated by spaces (" "). Is there a more pythonic way other than df['newcolumn'] = df['a'] + " " df['b'] + " " ...

```
a   b   c   combined
1   2   3   1 2 3
a   d   3   a d 3
p   0   k   p 0 k
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you are doing it, but a different way (perhaps more pythonic?) would be to:

```
df['newcolumn'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```

to make it more generalizable to large df's:

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.iloc[:,0:3].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```

where the `0:3` in iloc is just column indexes [0,1,2]. You could do this for any arbitrary selection of columns by selecting the proper indexes.

Comment: This is perfect, I have a dataframe that is 20 columns long so this last result really works wonders!

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` can be useful along `axis=1`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','a','p'], 
             'b':[2,'d',0],
             'c':[3,3,'k']})
df=df.astype(str)
df['combined']=df[df.columns].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will make the last column a list of all the values, but you can use the following:

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
a   b   c   combined
1   2   3   [1,2,3]
a   d   3   [a,d,3]
p   0   k   [p,0,k]
```